# Android: Copy file from PC to android device (Programmatically)

Tags: android, adb

I need to copy on a sqlite DB file onto the android device. Along with other files.

This is to be done by a delphi App. Ofc I can pull up console commands.

So basically, Can I copy to and take files from the devices.

Now, I have adb option.

```
 C:\Users\Documents>adb devices
 List of devices attached
 4527103425FC4D7 device
 HT25ZW127890    device


C:\Users\Documents>adb push -s HT25ZW127890 test.txt /sdcard/test.txt
```

But no idea how to target my device. It just lists all the options as if i typed in adb. And with out the -s bit, it says multiple devices attached.
What am I doing wrong? Plus...

Also: This is adb -> Android Debug Bridge. Which needs **Debug mode** set.

Surely this isn't the ideal way for a realised application, needing the phone in debug mode.

Comment: does this work in manually typing commands from console ? if not, then this question does not have relation to Delphi, only to android and ADB

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, Ogravity removed tag. sorry. You can type them in directly. Which is what Ive been trying. But if there are any other ways. Delphi and/or console Im for them.

Comment: there are applications that share Android disk via wifi network
---
there is Bluetooth
---
when u plug phone into computer it is seen as either USB thumb drive or Microsoft MTP-enabled device. 
--- 
for former you can work like with any disc. For latter MSDN has MediaPlayer 10 SDK which describes how to use MTP. ---
And also MSDN describes Windows Shell Explorer filename namespaces so that you probably can push/pull those files via Shell32.dll COM objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

This text suggests you have wrong positions for "-s" and "push" keywords.

> The usage is: 
>   adb [-d|-e|-s <serialNumber>] <command>

Comment: Yep. Push should have been after -s <serialNumber>. Is using adb for this task (not debugging, but infact live useage) the best method?

Comment: no one knows but you what would be best for your phones and your clients. too many variables so only you have chance to know the answer.  Personally i'd tried to copy as usual USB thumb drive or as MTP, for it does not require debug mode. But ADB seems kind of standard too. However "what is best method" is not the topic of this question.This question was "why adb does not work". Try the fix. If now it works, then accept the question please & start another topic if needed. (Though i think "what is best taste" kind of questions won't live long in SO, such questions are usually suited for forums)